# How much percent this number is close to another?

Tags: calculus

lets say I have two numbers. $Ideal$ as constant number and $Actual$ as variable number close to ideal.

I want to get percentage of how much Actual is close to Ideal. Ive tried this.

$Accuracy = Ideal/Actual * 100$

But this doesn't work. I want a right mathematic solution to get percentage of number being close to another.

As an example

$Ideal == Actual =>Accuracy = 100 \% $

$Ideal = 5, Actual = 2.5 => Accuracy = 50\%$

$Ideal = 5, Actual = 7.5 => Accuracy = 50\%$

$Ideal = 5, Actual = +-infinite => Accuracy = 0\%$

Comment: I think what you need is the [percent error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to map [Mean Percentage Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_percentage_error) to go from 0 -> 1 to infinity -> 0; however you also are looking for a rather linear relationship between ideal and actual for close values. There are two options:

1. Piecewise functions: What happens if actual = 0? If you say it should be 0%, then you would want an equation
   `Accuracy = Piecewise[{{1 - Abs[Actual - Ideal]/Ideal, 0 <= Actual <= 2Ideal}}]`
2. If you want your data to go to 0% accuracy only at inifinity, you're going to have to take the hit on linearity, and make it an exponential function of error
   `Accuracy = Exp[(-Abs[Actual - Ideal]/Ideal)]`

[A plot of the two curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFq6K.png)

Comment: yes. the formula `Accuracy = 100* e^-(abs(actual-ideal)/ideal)` works. though percentage error in other answer is correct. but for what I need I should get 0 if actual => infinity.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is the [percentage error](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/percentage-error.html). Its formula is:
$$
\textsf{PercentageError}
= \left| \frac{\textsf{Actual} - \textsf{Ideal}}{\textsf{Ideal}} \right| \cdot 100 \%
$$

Comment: What if the ideal value is 0? How can you determine how close a value is to 0?